# Using Kaa Notification with Kaa Data Collection feature

Tags: mongodb, logging, kaa

I want to use Kaa Notification in conjunction with Kaa Data Collection feature.

How can I implement my scenario for getting the logs?!

**Scenario is:**

**1-** Server send the notification to endpoint (using endpoint ID), then endpoint replies sending data with data collection feature.

**2-** Server wait a bit and check the timestamp of last appender record (I try with MongoDB log appender) for the endpoint (by endpoint ID).

**3-** "Add a notification listener that listens to all notifications:"

```
  kaaClient.addNotificationListener(new NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotification(long id, SecurityAlert sampleNotification) {
            LOG.info("Notification from the topic with id [{}] and name [{}] received.", id, getTopic(id).getName());
            LOG.info("Notification body: {} \n", sampleNotification.getAlertMessage());
            LOG.info("Notification alert type: {} \n", sampleNotification.getAlertType());

            inputTopicIdMessage();
        }
    });
```

**Requirement setting for logging:**

**1-** Added Configuration schema:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Configuration",
"namespace": "org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "samplingPeriod",
        "type": "int",
        "by_default": "1"
    }
]}
```

**2-** Added Log Schema:

```
{
"type":"record",
"name":"Data",
"namespace":"org.kaaproject.kaa.scheme.sample",
"fields":[
    {
        "name":"topicId",
        "type":"int"
    },
    {
        "name":"timeStamp",
        "type":"long"
    }
],
"displayName":"Logging scheme"
```

}

**3-** Added Log Appender with MongoDB.

After that I want to enable see logs with following commands:

```
db.logs_ApplicationToken.find();
```

---

**Updated (2017-12-03):**

I have run the following code similar to the Kaa Data Collection code for the Kaa Notification code:

```
    private static class MeasureSender implements Runnable {
    KaaClient kaaClient;

    MeasureSender(KaaClient kaaClient) {
        this.kaaClient = kaaClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sentRecordsCount.incrementAndGet();
        DataLogging record = generateTopicId();
        RecordFuture future = kaaClient.addLogRecord(record); // submit log record for sending to Kaa node
        LOG.info("Log record {} submitted for sending", record.toString());
        try {
            RecordInfo recordInfo = future.get(); // wait for log record delivery error
            BucketInfo bucketInfo = recordInfo.getBucketInfo();
            LOG.info("Received log record delivery info. Bucket Id [{}]. Record delivery time [{} ms].",
                    bucketInfo.getBucketId(), recordInfo.getRecordDeliveryTimeMs());
            confirmationsCount.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception was caught while waiting for log's delivery report.", e);
        }
    }
}

private static DataLogging generateTopicId() {
    //TODO: Logic for get topicId
    return new DataLogging(topicId, System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

After running application, When I run below command on Kaa server:

```
db.logs_18693008741969774929.find();
```

I get the result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a228679ef540e07f3e73cd6"), "header" : { "endpointKeyHash" :{ "string" : "dXhbOD271Qtg9+FhxHXfrjE9bw4=" }, "applicationToken" : { "string" : "18693008741969774929" }, "headerVersion" : { "int" : 1 }, "timestamp" : { "long": NumberLong("1512212089541") }, "logSchemaVersion" : { "int" : 5 } }, "event": { "topicId" : 0, "timeStamp": 0 } }
```

As a result, it shows that "topicId" has not been received. Because it is equal to 0.

As you can see in the last above method `private static DataLogging generateTopicId(){}`,
I need some logic for doing it.

---

**Updated (2017-12-06):**

```
public class NotificationDemo {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationDemo.class);
private static KaaClient kaaClient;
private static final int LOGS_DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 1;
private static int samplePeriodInSeconds = 1;
private static volatile AtomicInteger sentRecordsCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
private static volatile AtomicInteger confirmationsCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
private JsonObjectParserImpl jsonObjectParser = new JsonObjectParserImpl();
private String StatusOfDevices = String.valueOf(jsonObjectParser.getGetStatusOfDevices());

private static ScheduledExecutorService executor;
private static ScheduledFuture<?> executorHandle;
/**
 * The list of all available notification
 * <p>
 * private static int samplePeriodInSeconds = 1;
 * private static volatile AtomicInteger sentRecordsCount = new AtomicInteger0t;
 * private static volatile AtomicInteger confirmationsCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
 * <p>
 * private static Random rand = new Random(o;pics.
 */
private static List<Topic> topics;
/**
 * Topics client subscribed
 */
private static List<Topic> subscribedTopics = new ArrayList<Topic>();

InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader keyboardInput = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

public NotificationDemo() throws IOException, JSONException {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

    NotificationDemo main = new NotificationDemo();
    main.config();

}

public void config() {

    LOG.info("Notification demo started");

    //kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(new DesktopKaaPlatformContext(), new SimpleKaaClientStateListener(), true);
    KaaClient kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(new DesktopKaaPlatformContext(), new SimpleKaaClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            LOG.info("--= Kaa client started =--");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            LOG.info("--= Kaa client stopped =--");
        }
    }, true);

    /*
    * Set record count strategy for uploading every log record as soon as it is created.
     */
    kaaClient.setLogUploadStrategy(new RecordCountLogUploadStrategy(LOGS_DEFAULT_THRESHOLD));
/*
 * A listener that listens to the notification topic list updates.
 */
    kaaClient.addConfigurationListener(new ConfigurationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationUpdate(Configuration configuration) {
            LOG.info("--= Endpoint configuration was updated =--");
            displayConfiguration(configuration);

            Integer newSamplePeriod = configuration.getSamplingPeriod();
            if ((newSamplePeriod != null) && (newSamplePeriod > 0)) {
                changeMeasurementPeriod(kaaClient, newSamplePeriod);
            } else {
                LOG.warn("Sample period value (= {} in updated configuration is wrong, so ignore it.", newSamplePeriod);
            }
        }
    });
    NotificationTopicListListener topicListListener = new BasicNotificationTopicListListener();
    kaaClient.addTopicListListener(topicListListener);
    /*
     * Add a notification listener that listens to all notifications.
     */
    kaaClient.addNotificationListener(new NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotification(long id, Notification notification) {
            LOG.info("Notification from the topic with id [{}] and name [{}] received.", id, getTopic(id).getName());
            LOG.info("Notification body: {} \n", notification.getMessage());
            String commands = (notification.getMessage());
            if (commands.equals("arm")) {
                System.out.println("The Status of Devices:" + StatusOfDevices);
            }
            inputTopicIdMessage();
        }
    });
    /*
     * Start the Kaa client and connect it to the Kaa server.
     */
    kaaClient.start();


    topics = kaaClient.getTopics();

        /*
         * List the obtained notification topics.
         */
    showTopics();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextLong())

    {
        long topicId = scanner.nextLong();
        if (getTopic(topicId) != null) {
            LOG.info("Subscribing to optional topic {}", topicId);
            subscribeTopic(topicId);
        } else {
            LOG.info("There is no input topic id. Please, input existing topic id.");
        }
    }
    /*
     * Stop listening to the notification topic list updates.
     */
    kaaClient.removeTopicListListener(topicListListener);

    unsubscribeOptionalTopics();

    /*
     * Stop the Kaa client and release all the resources which were in use.
     */
    kaaClient.stop();
    LOG.info("Notification demo stopped");
}

private static void changeMeasurementPeriod(KaaClient kaaClient, Integer newPeriod) {
    if (executorHandle != null) {
        executorHandle.cancel(false);
    }
    samplePeriodInSeconds = newPeriod;
    executorHandle = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MeasureSender(kaaClient), 0, samplePeriodInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LOG.info("Set new sample period = {} seconds.", samplePeriodInSeconds);
}

private static class MeasureSender implements Runnable {
    KaaClient kaaClient;

    MeasureSender(KaaClient kaaClient) {
        this.kaaClient = kaaClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sentRecordsCount.incrementAndGet();
        DataLogging record = generateTopicId();
        RecordFuture future = kaaClient.addLogRecord(record); // submit log record for sending to Kaa node
        LOG.info("Log record {} submitted for sending", record.toString());
        try {
            RecordInfo recordInfo = future.get(); // wait for log record delivery error
            BucketInfo bucketInfo = recordInfo.getBucketInfo();
            LOG.info("Received log record delivery info. Bucket Id [{}]. Record delivery time [{} ms].",
                    bucketInfo.getBucketId(), recordInfo.getRecordDeliveryTimeMs());
            confirmationsCount.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception was caught while waiting for log's delivery report.", e);
        }
    }
}

private static DataLogging generateTopicId() {
    Integer topicId = generateTopicId().getTopicId();
    return new DataLogging(topicId, System.currentTimeMillis());
}

private static void inputTopicIdMessage() {
    LOG.info("\nPlease, type topic ID in order to subscribe to ones or type any text to exit: \n");
}

private static void displayConfiguration(org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample.Configuration configuration) {
    LOG.info("Configuration = {}", configuration.toString());
}

private static void showTopics() {
    if (topics == null || topics.isEmpty()) {
        LOG.info("Topic list is empty");
        return;
    }

    LOG.info("Available topics:");
    for (Topic topic : topics) {
        LOG.info("Topic id: {}, name: {}, type: {}", topic.getId(), topic.getName(), topic.getSubscriptionType());
    }

    LOG.info("Subscribed on topics:");
    for (Topic t : getOneTypeTopics(SubscriptionType.MANDATORY_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
        LOG.info("Topic id: {}, name: {}, type: {}", t.getId(), t.getName(), t.getSubscriptionType().name());
    }
    /*
     * Optional topics
     */
    if (!subscribedTopics.isEmpty()) {
        for (Topic t : subscribedTopics) {
            LOG.info("Topic id: {}, name: {}, type: {}", t.getId(), t.getName(), t.getSubscriptionType().name());
        }
    }
    inputTopicIdMessage();
}


private static List<Topic> getOneTypeTopics(SubscriptionType type) {
    List<Topic> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Topic t : NotificationDemo.topics) {
        if (t.getSubscriptionType() == type) {
            res.add(t);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private static void subscribeTopic(long topicId) {
    try {
        subscribedTopics.add(getTopic(topicId));
        kaaClient.subscribeToTopic(topicId, true);
    } catch (UnavailableTopicException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    inputTopicIdMessage();
}

private static Topic getTopic(long id) {
    for (Topic t : topics)
        if (t.getId() == id)
            return t;
    return null;
}

private static void sleepForSeconds(int seconds) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void unsubscribeOptionalTopics() {
    List<Topic> topics = getOneTypeTopics(SubscriptionType.OPTIONAL_SUBSCRIPTION);

    for (Topic t : subscribedTopics) {
        try {
            kaaClient.unsubscribeFromTopic(t.getId());
        } catch (UnavailableTopicException e) {
            // if not subscribe
        }
    }
}


private static void waitForAnyInput() {
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.warn("Error happens when waiting for user input.", e);
    }
}

/**
 * A listener that tracks the notification topic list updates
 * and subscribes the Kaa client to every new topic available.
 */
private static class BasicNotificationTopicListListener implements NotificationTopicListListener {
    @Override
    public void onListUpdated(List<Topic> list) {
        LOG.info("Topic list was updated:");
        topics.clear();
        topics.addAll(list);

        showTopics();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I need more info to help you. What's your notification schema? What's `SecurityAlert`? What `topicId` do you expect? Could you publish the code of your application? (It's hard to grasp the whole flow from a couple of snippets.)

Comment: I've changed the code. I just to try for the understanding relationship between Notification and Data Collection (Logging).

1. Notification schema is: { 
    "type":"record",
    "name":"ExampleNotification",
    "namespace":"org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample.notification",
    "fields":[ 
        { 
            "name":"message",
            "type":"string"
        }
    ]
}
2. About "topicId"; I want to collect data. Do you have any good suggestion for doing it?
3. I published the code. (refer to the new update.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer though I am not completely sure. (It is completely unclear what you're trying to achieve.)

First of all, I must say that data logging and notifications are completely orthogonal features. That means they do not interact in any way.

> As a result, it shows that "topicId" has not been received. Because it is equal to 0.

This is likely caused by your application not setting `topicId` at all. (e.g., calling `new DataLogging()` without arguments.)

> 2. About "topicId"; I want to collect data. Do you have any good suggestion for doing it?

From Kaa perspective, this `topicId` is  just an integer field and the server does not really care—it'll save in mongo whatever you send. If your goal is to collect *any* data, just put a random integer in there.

```
private static DataLogging generateTopicId() {
    Integer topicId = 42;
    return new DataLogging(topicId, System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```